# Apple Push Notifications - Remove Badge But Not Notification Text

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, ios6, apple-push-notifications

We have a requirement in our iOS5/6 app to remove the badge number from our app icon, but leave the notification text in the notification center.  Setting the badge number to 0 clears out the notification text as well.

Our potential solution is to set the badge number to -1, which seems to do exactly what we are looking for.  Does anyone else have any experience with doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as expected in iOS 5 and 6.0.  We are able to remove the badge icon, but not the notification text by setting the badge number to -1.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the app and set the application badge to 0, all the notifications of the notification center are cleared.

Comment: Understood, I am looking for a way to reset the badge number without clearing the notifications.  I have an approach that works, and am looking for validation or alternatives.